# How can I remove just one element in a selected element, leaving another?

Tags: jquery

I want to replace old `ul` with new by `empty();` and `append` method but its removing anchor tag also, How can I prevent removing anchor tag with it.

```
       <li class="show-ul">
        <a href="#" onClick="test()">show</a>
           <ul>
               <li> one </li>
               <li> two </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

JS

```
$(".show-ul").empty().append(newUL);
```

Comment: jQuery has several ways to remove individual elements. You chose the nuclear option. | [Remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), [Detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't empty the `li`, just replace the `ul`:

```
$(".show-ul > ul").replaceWith(newUL);
```

https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/